# Protocol for commenting on multi-line functions in R

Tags: r, function, comments

I know that if we want to comment on a line of code in R, we would use the following format

```
my.object <- function(A = arg(1))  #Comment
```

However, I have some code written that is broken into two lines. An example would be

```
my.object <- function(A = arg(1), B = arg(2),
                      C = arg(3), D = arg(4))
```

My question is this: If I wanted to comment on the second function, where would I place it? Should it go two spaces after line #1, two spaces after line #2, or should I perhaps place it above?

Comment: A good practice would be to include a multiline comment like this *"Some comment within double quotes"* explaining the function below it.

Answer (score 2):

You can comment in either place (and you don't actually need the spaces. The parser ignores everything from the hash to the next linefeed. They're only there for us humans:

```
my.object <- function(A = arg(1), B = arg(2),  # First two args
                      C = arg(3), D = arg(4))  # Second two and closing paren  
 {}
```

The comments may get excised when the function gets compiled or sourced.
I use both same line comments as well as "prefacatory comments" on earlier lines. Depends on how much I want to say. (I usually don't say enough.)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be -

```
"This function takes 4 args
and does something"
my.object <- function(A = arg(1), B = arg(2),
                      C = arg(3), D = arg(4))
```

Alternatively -

```
if(FALSE){
"We have a function below that takes 4 arguments
and does something"
}
my.object <- function(A = arg(1), B = arg(2),
                      C = arg(3), D = arg(4))
```

Commenting is all about making your code well documented and to occasionally explain some quirks. In `RStudio`, **`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `c`** helps to comment a selected line with the default spacing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this better than using actual comments with `#`?

Comment: @Roland it's just superfluous flair. Personally subscribe to 42- 's answer. Just giving alternate methods to produce multi-line comments.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use double quotes to comment multi-line code:

```
"my.object <- function(A = arg(1), B = arg(2),
                  C = arg(3), D = arg(4))"
```

Comment: He meant where does he put the comments in the code. The function is not to be commented out.